# Adjust QCheckbox into QTableWidget : Qt

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qtablewidget, qcheckbox

I am facing issues when I adjust `QCheckbox` into `QTableWidget`.

It is working as expected in Mac and Linux but creating problem in Windows.

I have googled it and tried out different solutions, but it did not solve my problem.

**Code:**

```
QWidget* cellWidget = new QWidget();
QCheckBox *box = new QCheckBox();
box->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout(cellWidget);
layout->addWidget(box);
layout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
layout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
cellWidget->setLayout(layout);
ui->twidget_header->setCellWidget(0, 0, cellWidget);
```

**Mac OS O/P : As Expected**

[image]
**Win OS O/P : Problem with Checkbox size and alignment**

[image]
.

My app is created in `Qt 5.9` for Mac, Win and Linux platform.
Let me know if you required more info about the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can happen with any QWidget while you create Qt app and support different resolutions.

To overcome the size of the `QWidget` (QCheckbox/QRadiobutton), you just need to overwrite the QWidget class.

Create `customcheckbox.h` file and overwrite the `QCheckbox` widget.

```
class CustomCheckBox : public QCheckBox
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
    CustomCheckBox(QWidget *parent=NULL);

private:
    bool m_isChecked;

public slots:
    void emitToggleSignal(bool);
};
```

Implement `customcheckbox.cpp` file as per your requirement.

By doing this, `QCheckbox` will automatically adjust size on respective resolution.

Hope this will save someone's time in future.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The design and size of the widgets are determined by the style. To override the native style (whatever `QApplication` sets as default on your target system) you'll have to derive your own [`QStyle`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html) for that target system and and reimplement [`pixelMetric()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#pixelMetric) to return the appropriate values for `QStyle::PM_IndicatorWidth` and `QStyle::PM_IndicatorHeight` (I think; didn't check that).

Comment: I have try this one but dint solved my problem. I got the solution and posting as an answer so, it will save someone else time in future.